# msys path conversion (or cygpath for msys?)

Tags: path, portability, mingw32, msys, cygpath

I need to pass /DEF:c:\filepath\myLib.def" command line option from a bash script to MS compiler/linker. The path is generated as part of build process by a bash script. Basically, the argument that my script passes is:

```
-DEF:/c/filepath/myLib.def
```

[MSYS path conversion](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion) can't handle it properly because it doesn't understand `/DEF:` part. It works if I do

```
-DEF=/c/filepath/myLib.def
```

but then ms tools don't understand this parameter. In short, what's the proper way to write that parameter in MSYS bash so that it converts it to proper argument?

On cygwin I could use cygpath, but there is no equivalent, because somebody from msys thinks that it's not needed (even if there are scripts for cygwin that uses cygpath).

Comment: The "not needed" argument can be stretched a long way. But sometimes it's useful, for example with Jython's shell script allowing for Cygwin but not MSYS. Jython's shell script calls `cygpath`. If we add `cygpath.exe` from @user1307996's answer into MSYS bin, it works.

Comment: Both directions handled here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13701218/321973

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Try to convert `\Windows` to posix using these hairy scripts. It makes no sense not to use cygpath on cygwin

Comment: of course not, unless you don't _have_ `cygpath` available...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem described has been solved in a later version of the software - msys2 includes cygpath.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Update (Aug-2016):**

This question is no longer relevant, as [msys2](https://msys2.github.io/) now comes with `cygpath` in its installation.

...

I'll summarize my research here.

The **cygpath** equivalent in MSYS is to use this command:

```
{ cd /c/some/path && pwd -W; } | sed 's|/|\\|g'
```

The problem with this approach is that it requires existing path, e.g. the `c:\some\path` has to be an existing directory; however, real **cygpath** supports paths that do not exist.

So, if you need to get path to a directory that doesn't exist, then you can fallback to sed conversion of the path:

```
{ cd 2>/dev/null /c/some/path && pwd -W ||
  echo /c/some/path | sed 's|^/\([a-z,A-Z]\)/|\1:/|'; } | sed 's|/|\\|g'
```

The mouthful of slashes is there to satisfy quoting rules of `sed`. So, if `c:\some\path` doesn't exist on your PC, it will try to convert forward to back slashes and replace `/c/` with `c:\` (or any other drive letter). The only drawback for this is that it won't work correctly non-existing paths that contain a mounted component, such as `/bin/does-not-exist` or `/usr/bin/does-not-exist`.

One more approach is to use **cygpath** from cygwin in MSYS. It seems that cygwin sets global environment variable CYGPATH, that is, you can use it from regular cmd.exe:

```
%CYGPATH% -w /c/some/path
C:\some\path
```

or from MSYS:

```
$CYGPATH -w /c/some/path
C:\some\path
```

as long as you set to point `/c` to `/cygdrive/c` in cygwin.
But this approach will print you `/usr` located in cygwin installation, not in MSYS.

In short, I think msys should really include real cygpath in the default set of tools just for some cases that aren't handled automatically by msys command line argument conversion logic

Comment: There's no need to escape backslashes if you are already using single-quotes.

Comment: Excellent answer, however if your sed script is modified to change \([a-z]\) to \([a-z,A-Z]\) , then capital drive letters may be used too.

Comment: Also, by removing the forwars slashes at the end of the first sed script it allows something like /c to be converted to C: instead of \c.

Comment: @stellarpower But then `/abc` will also get converted to `a:bc` or `a:\bc` depending on what `/a` gets converted to.

Comment: The sed part is imprecise - `pwd -W` generates uppercase drive letter whereas sed keeps the lowercase one (yes, this does matter sometimes).

Comment: The issue with any `sed` approach is that it depends on "only get paths that have the "/x/" form. But there can be different mount points that don't match this, most important ones are "/mingw" and "/home/".
The best option is to always use `pwd -W` for the first part of the entry, then convert /->\ and uppercase the first character (`pwd -W` converts according to the mounts and may also use lowercase letters).

Answer (score 14):

use `pwd -W`

or 
download cygpath for msys from here http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/enhanced-version-of-cygpath-td28556.html

and use `cygpath -wa`

Comment: How is it different from my own answer?

Comment: link I provided points to cygpath.exe that is probably different from cygwin one.

Comment: The link provided provides a cygpath that doesn't work properly. E.g. `cygpath -w /c/foobar` prints `c:/foobar` while it should print `c:\foobar`.

Answer (score 8):

Similar to dmitri-rubinstein@ above, I've cleaned up the code a bit and added the reverse conversion as well.

```sh
winpath() {
    if [ ${#} -eq 0 ]; then
        : skip
    elif [ -f "$1" ]; then
        local dirname=$(dirname "$1")
        local basename=$(basename "$1")
        echo "$(cd "$dirname" && pwd -W)/$basename" \
        | sed \
          -e 's|/|\\|g';
    elif [ -d "$1" ]; then
        echo "$(cd "$1" && pwd -W)" \
        | sed \
          -e 's|/|\\|g';
    else
        echo "$1" \
        | sed \
          -e 's|^/\(.\)/|\1:\\|g' \
          -e 's|/|\\|g'
    fi
}

unixpath() {
    echo "$1" \
    | sed -r \
      -e 's/\\/\//g' \
      -e 's/^([^:]+):/\/\1/'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using this with msysgit:

```
winpath() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "$@"
    else
        if [ -f "$1" ]; then
            local dir=$(dirname "$1")
            local fn=$(basename "$1")
            echo "$(cd "$dir"; echo "$(pwd -W)/$fn")" | sed 's|/|\\|g';
        else
            if [ -d "$1" ]; then
                echo "$(cd "$1"; pwd -W)" | sed 's|/|\\|g';
            else
                echo "$1" | sed 's|^/\(.\)/|\1:\\|g; s|/|\\|g';
            fi
        fi
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My bash foo is weak and I couldn't get regexes working in bash 3.1 so I hacked out a perl script for it:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;

my @r;
foreach my $e (@ARGV) {
 $e=~s/\//\\/g;
 $e=~s/^\\([A-Za-z])\\/\1:\\/;
 push @r, $e;
}

print join(" ", @r);
```

Comment: I know how to do that using scripts; I think that there is some MSYS specific way to quote arguments so that it converts this path automatically. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

### MSYS `cygpath`

#### Program

This program convert a DOS path to a UNIX path and vice versa

```perl
#!/bin/env perl
# DOS to UNIX path conversion
# © John S. Peterson. License GNU GPL 3.
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;

# usage
if ($#ARGV == -1) {
    print 'Usage: cygpath (-w) NAME...

Convert Unix and Windows format paths

Output type options:

  -w, --windows         print Windows form of NAMEs (C:\WINNT)
';
    exit 0;
}

# option
my %opt;
getopts('w', \%opt);

# convert path
my @r;
foreach my $e (@ARGV) {
    if ($opt{w}) {
        # add drive letter suffix
        $e =~ s,^\/([A-Za-z])\/,\1:\/,;
        $e =~ s,\/,\\,g;

    } else {
        $e =~ s,\\,\/,g;
        # add leading slash
        $e = "/$e";
        # remove drive letter suffix
        $e =~ s,:,,;
    }

    push @r, $e;
}

print join("\n", @r);
```

#### Compared to Cygwin `cygpath`

The output from this program is better than the output from Cygwin `cygpath` in MSYS because

- Cygwin `cygpath` remove the Cygwin home from a converted path, f.e.

```
cygpath "$CYGWIN/usr/local/bin"
/usr/local/bin
```

which is a problem because

- it's sometimes useful to convert a DOS Cygwin path to a UNIX path for the purpose of copying files from Cygwin to MSYS

This program doesn't remove the Cygwin home

```
cygpath "$CYGWIN/usr/local/bin"
/c/file/program/cygwin/usr/local/bin
```

#### Compared to automatic MSYS path conversion

Manual path conversion has a use in MSYS because

- the automatic path conversion is inadequate

for f.e.

- [devkitPro `make`](https://github.com/mirror/dolphin-emu/pull/31)

Answer (score 3):

How about this one ?
`cmd //c echo <your path>`

It may not work always but it is the shortest I found

Comment: Solution based on this how to pass it from a Makefile is provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257679/how-do-i-define-a-path-from-an-msys-makefile-for-a-c-program/40257680#40257680

Comment: Commented there that the syntax may actually be causing issues for me, and a slight change to `cmd /c echo ...` may work better.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```sh
df "$1" | tac >k
read b <k
rm k
set "$1" $b
echo ${1/$7/$2/}
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/wrapper/notepad2)

Comment: Did you try my own solution: `sh -c 'cd /c/some/path; pwd -W'`? it's functionally equivalent to `cygpath -w '/c/some/path'` on cygwin. Your solution maybe has that functionality of cygpath, but it's not very clear how to translate it to cygpath-like command.

Answer (score -1):

*nearly* pure GNU bash solution (which is what you commonly run in MSYS) (interestingly not working with MSYS2, leave a comment if you know why):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# check if we have cygpath (cygwin, newer MSYS2), then just use that 
which cygpath 1>/dev/null 2>&1
[[ $? = 0 ]] && (cygpath -wa "$1"; exit $?)

# check if it looks like a Windows path, in which case we directly convert and exit
[[ ${1} =~ ^[a-zA-Z]: ]] && \
  echo "${1}" | sed -e 's|/|\\|g' -e 's/\(.\)/\u\1/' && exit 0

# split first path entry (if any) with trailing slash and filename
[[ ${1} =~ ^\([/a-zA-Z0-9_.-]\\w*/\)?\(.*\)$ ]]

chk_root="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
chk_rest="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

# check if the root path exists and more important: let pwd binary resolve the translation according to the mount
chk_winroot="$(cd "${chk_root}." 2>/dev/null && pwd -W)"
[[ "${chk_winroot}" == "" ]] && echo "${chk_root}: No such file or directory" && exit 1

# using substition to replace all / by \ and uppercasing the first character
# pure bash solution; sadly: the first part needs a newer bash than old MSYS have ...
# chk_drv="${chk_winroot:0:1}"
# chk_all="${chk_winroot:1}/${chk_rest}"
# echo "${chk_drv^^}${chk_all//\//\\}"

# ... so fallback to GNU sed
echo "${chk_winroot}/${chk_rest}" | sed -e 's|/|\\|g' -e 's/\(.\)/\u\1/'
```

There's still an issue with it: if MinGW's fstab contains an entry like `/mnt/c` the `pwd -W` of `/mnt/.` done in this script won't work.
To fix it: replace `pwd -W` by inspecting `$ cat /etc/fstab | cut -d'#' -f1 | grep -v "^\s*$"` entries manually and replace the first match - while this will never work for cygwin or msys2 which use a different format this is covered by using cygpath there.

Comment: Is there any reason to use it now when MSYS2 ships `cygpath`?

Comment: Yes, if you use the original MSYS (or a very old MSYS2). Because of completely different dependencies and missing support for "old" Windows versions one may still want to use MSYS/MinGW instead of MSYS2's environments.