# Windows PATH to posix path conversion in bash

Tags: windows, string, bash, path, msys

How can I convert a **Windows** dir path (say `c:/libs/Qt-static`) to the correct **POSIX** dir path (`/c/libs/Qt-static`) by means of standard **msys** features? And vice versa?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I don't know `msys`, but a quick google search showed me that it includes the `sed` utility. So, assuming it works similar in `msys` than it does on native Linux, here's one way how to do it:

### From Windows to POSIX

You'll have to replace all backslashes with slashes, remove the first colon after the drive letter, and add a slash at the beginning:

```
echo "/$pth" | sed 's/\\/\//g' | sed 's/://'
```

or, as noted by xaizek,

```
echo "/$pth" | sed -e 's/\\/\//g' -e 's/://'
```

### From POSIX to Windows

You'll have to add a semi-colon, remove the first slash and replace all slashes with backslashes:

```
echo "$pth" | sed 's/^\///' | sed 's/\//\\/g' | sed 's/^./\0:/'
```

or more efficiently,

```
echo "$pth" | sed -e 's/^\///' -e 's/\//\\/g' -e 's/^./\0:/'
```

where `$pth` is a variable storing the Windows or POSIX path, respectively.

Comment: @Dukales I can't test this, so does this work? If not, what are the error messages?

Comment: In Windows to POSIX leading slash is superfluous.

Comment: @Dukales: ...why? AFAIK, without the leading slash it indicates a *relative* path, wheras the leading slash makes it an *absolute* path w.r.t. the filesystem root

Comment: I mean that the `$PATH` is the standard envvar.

Comment: @Dukales: ah, like so. That is entirely true. I intended `$PATH` to be a user-defined variable; I'll edit.

Comment: You know, there is no need to pipe several invocations of `sed`, just pass multiple `-e command` arguments to single instance (like `sed -e one -e two`).

Comment: when using the bash shipped with git, the drive letter needs to be lowercased, and some folder names may begin with a '$' - try this:
`echo "$pth" | sed -e 's#\\#/#g' -e 's#\$#/\\$#g' -e 's#^\([a-zA-Z]\):#/\L\1#`

Comment: When converting a strings with multiple paths from Windows to POSIX, a leading / has to be added to every path. The more effiicient command version will become: `echo "$pth" | sed -e 's/\\/\//g' -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]\):/\/\1/g'`

Comment: @Francois Perhaps case is irrelevant now. My version of bash `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(3)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)` with git `2.6.3.windows.1` accepts `/C` or `/c` as equivalent.

Comment: In Git Bash (at least; I don't know how Cygwin or other POSIX compatible shells in Windows treat Windows paths), the path prefix `X:` (where `X` is the driver letter) becomes `/x`, so `sed 's/://'` should be changed to `sed -r 's|^([^:]+):|\/\L\1|'` (at least when used in Git Bash; I also took the liberty to change `/` to `|` as I personally find this much less confusing in `sed` scripts).

Comment: This assumes C: is mounted on /c etc. which is not necessarily the case (true for git-bash, false for cygwin)

Answer (score 79):

Cygwin, Git Bash, and MSYS2 have a readymade utility called `cygpath.exe` just for doing that.

```
Output type options:
  -d, --dos             print DOS (short) form of NAMEs (C:\PROGRA~1\)
  -m, --mixed           like --windows, but with regular slashes (C:/WINNT)
  -M, --mode            report on mode of file (binmode or textmode)
  -u, --unix            (default) print Unix form of NAMEs (/cygdrive/c/winnt)
  -w, --windows         print Windows form of NAMEs (C:\WINNT)
  -t, --type TYPE       print TYPE form: 'dos', 'mixed', 'unix', or 'windows'
```

Comment: Have a look at this mail: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=8686481

Comment: Whoever has downvoted this answer, please also comment about any mistake, so that I could rectify... :-)

Comment: `cygpath` appears to work on MINGW64 (git bash). Not sure if it's because I have cygwin installed as well or has been added since this question - but I got the expected outcome from `cygpath 'd:\something'` - how could it automatically translate a string from the clipboard or custom environment variable?

Comment: @hood: _"Not sure if it's because I have cygwin installed as well"_ yes, that's the likely explanation... _"how could it automatically translate a string from the clipboard or custom environment variable"_ Not sure what is expected here.

Comment: Only small caveat, the utility only converts any path string, does not check to see the path exists.

Comment: @SGM1: I think, that's good/intentional. e.g. you may want to do this: `mkdir C:\temp\new_dir` So, you would do `mkdir /cygdrive/c/temp/new_dir`, using `cygpath` to convert the paths. If `cygpath` had been checking the existence of the target, you would not be able to convert such paths...

Comment: sooo anoying when utilities don't support -- from std in
`pwd | cygpath -w --` is preferrable over to `cygpath -w $(pwd)` <sigh/>

Comment: `cygpath.exe` comes included when you install git-bash. You don't need to have cygwin or even know what cygwin is. It's in path when you're using git-bash

Comment: @ZYinMD, But then you need to install git-bash. I don't have to install git if I don't need to. Basically, many softwares are cygwin based (like git-bash) and ship a minimal version of cygwin. You can use whatever you have. I have been using cygwin for a long time without having or even knowing git-bash. cygpath.exe comes installed with cygwin.

Comment: Yes @anishsane, I should've have worded my comment differently. What I meant was "btw if you (the reader) have already installed git-bash (many do, in 2020), then you already have cygpath in path, without needing to know what cgwin is.

Comment: Thank you... :-) On an unrelated note, I have moved from cygwin to WSL2.

Answer (score 28):

Just use `cygpath`:

```
$ cygpath -w "/c/foo/bar"
 -> C:\foo\bar

$ cygpath -u "C:\foo\bar"
 -> /c/foo/bar
```

You may wonder: "Do I have `cygpath` installed?" Well,

1. If you're in git-bash, then yes.
2. If you're in cygwin or MSYS2, then yes.
3. If you're in another shell, but you have installed git-bash before, then `cygpath` can be found at `git-bash-install-folder\usr\bin\cygpath.exe`.
4. Else: maybe not, but I'm sure you can find a way to installed it.

Answer (score 9):

The "correct" way in MSYS is:

```
$ MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1  taskkill /F /T /IM ssh-agent.exe
```

This avoids having to manually translate slashes. It simply de-activates the path conversion.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my implementation (tested on git bash).

### From POSIX to Windows

```
sed '
    \,/$, !s,$,/,
    \,^/, s,/,:/,2
    s,^/,,
    s,/,\\,g
    ' <<< "$@"
```

**Works for:**

```
/c/git
relative/dir
c:/git
~
.
..
/c
/c/
./relative/dir
/sd0/some/dir/
```

*except*

```
/
<path with space>
```

**Explanation:**

`\,^/, s,/,:/,2` (converts `/drive/dir/` to `/drive:/dir/`) is the heart of it and inserts `:` before the `2`nd `/`. I use `,` for delim instead of `/` for readability. If starting with `/` (`\,^/,`), then replace `/` with `:/` for the `2`nd occurrence. I do not want to assume drive letter length of 1 so this works for `/sd0/some/dir`.

`s,^/,,` removes the leading `/` and `s,/,\\,g` converts all `/` to `\`.

`\,/$, !s,$,/,` is to handle the corner case of `/c` and ensure 2nd `/` (`/c/`) for the next command to work.

Note:

If here string `<<<` does not work in your shell then you can `echo` and pipe as

```
echo "$@" | sed ...
```

**Errata**

Here [e script](https://github.com/rmandvikar/git-setup/blob/next/bin/e)

Answer (score 4):

just FYI - at least for my git version 2.26.2.windows.1
e.g. if I have a path like C:\dev\work_setup\msk, I can go directly to Git Bash and type

```
cd "C:\dev\work_setup\msk"
```

this will result in current folder being changed to /c/dev/work_setup/msk - so this type of conversion seems to be done automatically, as long as I put the Windows path inside double quotes. Unfortunately I don't have references to original documentation that would back that up.

Comment: This worked for me whereas "cygpath --unix" did not, it returned the path minus any slashes.

Answer (score 1):

My solution works with a list of folders/files and it's done in 2 steps.
Suppose you would like to replace a path from ***D:\example*** to ***/example*** for a list of file where this Windows path has been repetead.

The first step it changes the backlashes into slashes

```
grep -lr "D:\\\\example" /parent-folder | xargs -d'\n' sed -i 's+\\+\/+g'
```

Note that ***parent-folder*** could be root (/) or whatever you like and ***-d'\n'*** parameter is necessary if you have filenames or folder names with white spaces.

Second step it substitutes the D:/example into /example:

```
grep -lr "D:/example" /parent-folder | xargs -d'\n' sed -i 's+D:+/example+g'
```

I wanted to share this solution since it tooks me some time to make this 2 lines but it has been really helpfull job (I'm migrating a Windows App to a Linux Server with tons of Windows paths inside').

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @hello_earth is misleading, due to Windows path must be double backslashed like:

```
cd "e:\\dir\\subdir\\path"
```

otherwise the shell will find escape-sequences.