# How to convert a DOS-style path to Unix-style path under MSYS using simple commands?

Tags: bash, path, dos, msys

For instance, if I have this as input:

```
F:\my\path\to\File.TXT
```

I want to get this as output

```
/f/my/path/to/File.TXT
```

This should work even if the path doesn't exist, so I can't simply call

```
cd $P && pwd -P
```

Edit: I'd like to avoid using *sed* and *awk*, since there are simpler commands to achieve this, like *tr* and Bash built-ins.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows PATH to posix path conversion in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701218/windows-path-to-posix-path-conversion-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

These 2 Bash functions will help:

```
canondirslashes() { local p; p="$(echo $1 | tr \\ /)" && echo ${p%/}; }

canonpath() { canondirslashes "$( test "${1:1:1}" != : && echo $1 || echo $(echo /${1::1} | tr [A-Z] [a-z])${1:2} )" ; }
```

Here's an example:

```
bash-3.1$ P=F:\\my\\path\\to\\File.TXT

bash-3.1$ echo $P
F:\my\path\to\File.TXT

bash-3.1$ canonpath $P
/f/my/path/to/File.TXT
```