# What is the difference in command line argument syntax between bat and sh?

Tags: git, bash, shell, batch-file, robocopy

I am trying to run **robocopy** (Windows robust copy) in a shell script (which is actually a git hook). It works fine until I add the option `/XO`.

So the command:

```
robocopy source destination a.txt
```

works correctly in .bat and .sh file.

But the command

```
robocopy source destination a.txt /XO
```

fails in .sh with error:

> ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "C:/Program Files/Git/XO"

whereas it works correctly in bat file.

So the problem is with the `/XO` option to **robocopy**; more specifically, the way shells script passes the parameter to **robocopy**.

Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: So, this git bash is based on cygwin or msys? with [`msys`this problem should not arise](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=8686481).

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701218/windows-path-to-posix-path-conversion-in-bash/13702694#13702694

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Git Bash` for this, it intelligently transforms Unix-style options in to Windows-style ones. So, for example, the command:

```
robocopy source destination a.txt -xo
```

will show you that it's using the `/xo` option:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Tue Feb 06 15:58:53 2018

   Source : c:\gitbashdir\source
     Dest : c:\gitbashdir\destination\

    Files : a.txt

  Options : /COPY:DAT /XO /R:1000000 /W:30

   : blah blah blah :

   Ended : Tue Feb 06 15:58:53 2018
```