# Fix paths on bash running on windows with MinGW

Tags: windows, bash, mingw

If I have a bash script like:

```
PATH_SCRIPT="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
echo "$PATH_SCRIPT"
```

If will echo something like:

```
/c/path/to/where/the/file/is
```

And generally, that is okay. But in some places, if running on windows, I'll actually need to parse this variable so it looks like this:

```
C:\path\to\where\the\file\is
```

How can I do that properly in bash and be able to pass it around?

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701218/windows-path-to-posix-path-conversion-in-bash) but I'll leave the question as written, because it may help people who don't know the wording to find the correct question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git-Bash, try

```
cygpath -aw /c/path/to/where/the/file/is
```

Comment: might be a useful answer for other people, but it seems like this is not available on MinGW

Comment: @Mefitico: It is available on MinGW nowdays. :)