# How do you open SourceTree from the command line?

Tags: git, command-line, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a quick and easy way to open a git repository in SourceTree from the command line?

I do a lot of git work from Terminal, but sometimes there's no replacement for a good history view/diff. Would love to be able to open without using bookmarks.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Installing the SourceTree Command Line Tools will provide you with the `stree` command. This will allow you to open the current directory in SourceTree.

[image: sourcetree commandline tools]

You can also specify a particular path to a repo

```
stree ~/my-repo-in-another-folder
```

---

If installing command-line tools isn't an option for whatever reason, you can also do the following:

```
open -a SourceTree path-to-file
```

and maybe set up an alias in .bashrc or .zshrc

```
alias sourcetree='open -a SourceTree'
```

For those who are using SourceTree 3

```
alias sourcetree='open -a SourceTree\ 3'
```

Comment: You can make your sourcetree alias open the git repository that's in the current working directory by changing it to `alias sourcetree='open -a SourceTree ./'`. Also Mac users may wish to place the alias in `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 47):

[The answer by loeschg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19663203/3169029) may not work; some people get an error referring to their system logs and cannot install the command line tools. [There is an open issue about this.](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-3172)

[A workaround is found here.](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/SourceTree-command-line-tools-installation-failed/qaq-p/85023/comment-id/2379#M2379) Use:

```
ln -s /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/stree /usr/local/bin/
```

This will create a symbolic link to the `stree` binary and put it in `/usr/local/bin`. Make sure that directory is on your path: `which stree` should result in `/usr/local/bin/stree`. If it does not, then add it to your `PATH` manually or use `echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`, which does it for you (restart your shell to reload the `PATH` variable).

On the above-mentioned issue's page, another workaround that I didn't test was posted: `alias stree='/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/stree'`. If you use it, please report in the comments if and how it works and why you'd prefer it over the symbolic link.

For both methods, the path to `stree` in `SourceTree.app` must of course match the location where you installed `SourceTree.app`.

Now, `stree` is installed and can be accessed from any directory. The shortest way to open SourceTree when your shell's working directory is a repository's root directory is `stree .`.

Comment: I prefer the `alias` method because it feels less "permanent" and more "portable" than creating a symbolic link in a directory that's already relatively full and feels like it's being managed automatically for me – Homebrew likes to symlink stuff from its Cellar there. Plus, SourceTree has been making changes recently to its UI that I don't appreciate, so I've started keeping multiple versions of it around, just in case. Using alias(es) gives me greater flexibility as to which version I'd like to target in bash.

Comment: I was also getting this error. What worked for me: simply update SourceTree to v3.0.1 (Sourcetree --> Check for Updates...). After updating it, Installing Command Line Tools was then working fine. :D (my Sourcetree was still on v2.7.6 when I got the error)

Answer (score 15):

For those of you on Windows, you can add a batch file named `stree.bat` to a folder in your PATH Environment Variable. (I have a `C:\batch` folder which is in my PATH where I store all my utility batch files.) Put the following in to your batch file:

```
@echo off
start "" "%LocalAppData%\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe" -f "%cd%"
```

(credit @Collin K below for the updated command)

Now you can go to any Git or Mercurial repository and run this command which will open the repository in SourceTree.

**Old answer:**

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe"
```

Comment: FYI: On my machine source tree is NOT installed in Program Files, its in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\SourceTree.  Probably because they're using the Squirrel installer now?

Comment: The command that works for me in 2023 is `start "" "%LocalAppData%\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe" -f "%cd%"`

Comment: @CollinK, thanks. Crucial addition! Works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Another Windows solution for those who use Git on the Bash command line (msys).

Add two functions to your Bash .profile:

```bash
# Courtesy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015348/msys-path-conversion-or-cygpath-for-msys
function towinpath {
    { cd $1 && pwd -W; } | sed 's|/|\\|g'
}

function stree {
    if [ -z $1 ]; then
        stree_path=$(towinpath pwd)
    else
        stree_path=$(towinpath $1)
    fi

    echo "Starting SourceTree in $stree_path"

    /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Atlassian/SourceTree/SourceTree.exe -f $stree_path status
}
```

Reload your shell.

Now you can use:

```
$ towinpath /c/Temp
```

And it will echo `c:\Temp`.

Or you can open SourceTree:

```
$ stree .
```

And it will open this repository in SourceTree defaulting to the Status panel.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! There's also a Cygwin function, `cygpath`, where you could do something akin to `function towinpath { cygpath -w $(cd $1 && pwd); }`. This will more robustly handle things such as UNC paths.

Answer (score 3):

If you have cygwin installed, you can use this as your `stree.bat`. This batch file uses `cygpath` to resolve `.` to its absolute path, so you can do `stree .`

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`cygpath -w -a %1`) DO (
SET STREE_OPEN_PATH=%%F
)
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe -f "%STREE_OPEN_PATH%"
```

Answer (score 2):

in `Windows` using `powershell`, from inside directory that you want to open in `SourceTree`:

```
& 'C:\Users\userexample\AppData\Local\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe' -f (Get-Location)
```

N.B: the path `C:\Users\userexample\AppData\Local\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe` can be changed to wherever `SourceTree` is installed,

for Exp: if SourceTree is installed  with admin privileges this path will be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe` and the command will become

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe' -f (Get-Location)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Windows

Adapting from multiple answers here for Windows, these scripts will allow you to get SourceTree running from command line (tested on SourceTree 3.0.1.7 / Windows 10).

### Scripts in a PATH directory

I've placed both these scripts in a folder that is in my system PATH. You won't have to modify your bash profile for this script.

#### Git Bash for Windows

Create a file named `stree` (`touch stree`) in your PATH linked directory and run `chmod u+x stree` on this file.

```
#!/bin/sh

function towinpath {
    { cd $1 && pwd -W; } | sed 's|/|\\|g'
}

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    stree_path=$(towinpath pwd)
else
    stree_path=$(towinpath $1)
fi

$LOCALAPPDATA/SourceTree/SourceTree.exe -f $stree_path log &
```

You can replace "log" in the last line with "status" if you prefer the changes/working directory view of your repository in SourceTree.

#### Command Prompt or Powershell

Create a file named `stree.cmd` in your PATH linked directory.

```
@echo off
start "" "%LOCALAPPDATA%\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe"
```

Note that this won't actually open up the directory as a repository.

Please feel free to improve the scripts, especially the one for Command Prompt.