# Jython 2.7 beta 1 under MSYS

Tags: shell, mingw, jython, msys

I installed jython 2.7 beta 1 on Windows and copied its `JYTHON_HOME/bin/jython` shell script into a `$PATH`-visible location for MSYS, but calling

```
$ jython
```

doesn't work, with this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/util/jython
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.python.util.jython
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.python.util.jython.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

Having a look at this `jython` shell script (which I renamed `jython.sh`), I see it expects either Cygwin or Darwin.

At the beginning of the file I added

```
export JAVA_HOME='/c/Programs/JavaRE/6u31'
export JYTHON_HOME='/c/Programs/jython2_7b1'
```

And then where it said

```
case "`uname`" in
  CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
  Darwin) darwin=true;;
esac
```

I replaced with

```
case "`uname`" in
  CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
  MINGW*) cygwin=true;;
  Darwin) darwin=true;;
esac
```

But it still doesn't work, with:

```
$ jython.sh test.j.py
/c/Programs/Path/jython.sh: line 265: /cygdrive/c/Programs/JavaRE/6u31/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Internally the `jython.sh` script uses `cygpath`, but MSYS doesn't have that, so it falls back on Cygwin's, leading to the above error. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to get MSYS's own version of `cygpath` from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cbadvanced/files/Msys%20Specific/cygpath-enhanced.7z/download

And put it into MSYS's `/bin`

Then running a script like this, works:

```
$ jython.sh test.j.py
```

More discussion about MSYS's `cygpath.exe` here, including why it's *not needed*: http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/enhanced-version-of-cygpath-td28556.html

(To be fair, if it were included in MSYS, then projects will start to rely on it, which is not necessarily the best idea ever.)

Thanks to this answer for the pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18488099/1143274