# change windows filenames to bash filenames

Tags: git, bash, mingw32

I'm using gitbash as my main console on windows. Often I want to copy in a filename from explorer and use it for git commands, this often doesn't work as git sometimes expects filenames in the form /c/directory/directory/filename rather than c:\directory\directory\filename.

I usually have to go in an manually edit the filename/path to be in the correct format, which is anoying if the file is many directories deep.

I've written a sed command to modify the string to be of the correct format:

```
sed 's:\\:/:g' | sed 's:\(.\)::/\1:g'
```

Is there a way I can make this a function or something so that I can do something like...

```
git add convert("c:\blah\blah\myfile.txt")
```

and what actually gets run is

```
git add /c/blah/blah/myfile.txt
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows PATH to posix path conversion in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701218/windows-path-to-posix-path-conversion-in-bash)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question as I'm asking for a way to call the sed command from bash in a nice way. I'm not asking for a sed command like that question was

Comment: [Opposite of this - convert bash path to windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015348/msys-path-conversion-or-cygpath-for-msys)

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
function git_add {
    git add "$(exec sed 's|\\|/|g; s|\(.\):|/\1|g' <<< "$1")"
}
```

and do:

```
git_add "c:\blah\blah\myfile.txt"
```

another way:

```
function convert {
    sed 's|\\|/|g; s|\(.\):|/\1|g' <<< "$1"
}

git add "$(convert "c:\blah\blah\myfile.txt")"
```

Comment: I want to do it for all things on command line, not just git, so would want something a bit more generic

Answer (score 0):

cygpath is in the gitbash distribution, so I use cygpath -u "c:\foo.xml"

I am currently running gitbash 2.31.1 on Win10