# Git Alias issue...see the screenshot

Tags: git, command, alias

This is the screenshot of git for windows when it starts up.  I added some git.bash profile information and a few global commands as follows, based on the other questions asked on this site.

[image]

Please assist me in getting these to stop running when git starts up and assign sublime as the default text editor.

Comment: I would have a look at the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#coreeditor-nPTEiMsRI9), where it talks about configuration, and what exactly are you trying to accomplish with your .profile (or other shell startup file) file.  It appears to have an error. (something is not found)

Comment: It seems that you have modified your text editor to be Sublime Text 3, which you don't have installed on the path in the error log. Please post your git.bash profile if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following:

1. Make sure you have installed Sublime Text in the specified path.
2. And you might need to use unix style path, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015348/msys-path-conversion-or-cygpath-for-msys).
3. Paths with spaces probably need to be quoted, here's an existing Q&A about [how to make Sublime Text as default editor for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git), though a different topic, but the problem to solve is quite similar.