# How do I define a path from an MSYS Makefile for a C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, msys, msys2

My problem: in a Makefile which I use in both the MSYS and the MSYS2 environment I know a path, PYTHON_ROOT_DIR, which shall be used at compilation time in a C++ program. Problem is PYTHON_ROOT_DIR is in the Makefile known as posix style path such as `/mingw64/bin`, where in the C++ program it shall have a form like `"C:\\prog64\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"`. Additional challenge is that depending on a configuration variable PYTHONMAJOR the path shall be wide characters or normal characters.

My question: how do I solve this in the Makefile without a need to install additional programs/scripts in the msys or msys2 environments?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the question is addressed in [msys path conversion (or cygpath for msys?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015348/msys-path-conversion-or-cygpath-for-msys), namely how to convert a msys style path to a windows style path. My full solution in the Makefile is:

```
ifeq ($(PYTHONMAJOR),3)
    L=L
endif
DEFINES += -DPYTHON_ROOT_DIR=$(L)'"'$(shell (cmd //c echo $(PYTHON_ROOT_DIR)) | sed 's|/|\\\\\\\\|g')'"'
```

which defines the preprocessor symbol PYTHON_ROOT_DIR with the proper path.

Comment: I thought this might be an issue with my Cygwin environment or any customizations, but I am finding this in libtool causing build issues for me causing sed to wait for input because this provides none.  Executing this in a plain `cmd` prompt opens a new process that does not quit.  Changing it to `cmd /c echo ...` may yield better results.

Comment: I guess cygwin is again different from msys...